# casting LinkedList<Object> to LinkedList<Customer>

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a method like this

```
public static LinkedList<Object> getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile(String className){
       LinkedList<Object> lstObj = new LinkedList<Object>();
       if(className.equals("Customer")){
            //read Data from XML File
            Customer customer = ...;
            lstObj.add(customer);
       }
       ....
       return lstObj;
}
```

after that i call this method and want to cast :

```
LinkedList<Customer> lstCustomer = (LinkedList<Customer>()) getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile("Customer");
```

But it cannot cast. 
How can i cast from LinkedList to LinkedList ? 
Pls help me ! thanks so much !

Comment: The syntax would be `(LinkedList<Customer>)`

Comment: While this is possible, this is an unsafe cast - the compiler cannot check it. I would suggest you return the correct class from your method. Use Generics properly `public static <T> LinkedList<T> getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile(Class<T> requiredClass)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your method to something like this:

```
public static <E> LinkedList<E> getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile(Class<E> type){
       LinkedList<E> lstObj = new LinkedList<E>();
       if (type.equals(Customer.class)) {
           Customer customer = ...
           lstObj.add((E)customer);
       }
       return lstObj;
}
```

By making the method generic and passing a `Class` parameter you can return a list of the right type.

You can call it this way

```
List<Customer> l = getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile(Customer.class);
```

Comment: +1 and note that using `type.cast(customer)` will avoid any unchecked cast warnings that come with `(E)customer`. Also, `type == Customer.class` would be equivalent (just saying).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create new List and add casted object to the new linked list of Customer.

```
LinkedList<Customer> custList = new LinkedList<>();
for(Object obj: getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile("Customer")) {
   custList.add((Customer)obj));
}
```

Or, it is better to use generics if possible as mentioned by "Boris the Spider" in comment.

```
 public static <T> LinkedList<T> getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile(Class<T> requiredClass)
```

The definition can be as follows as given by "micha".

```
public static <T> LinkedList<T> getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile(Class<T> requiredClass){
       LinkedList<T> listObj = new LinkedList<>();
       if (requiredClass.equals(Customer.class)) {
           Customer customer = /*...*/
           listObj.add((T)customer);
       }
       return listObj;
}
```

Then, You can call as

```
LinkedList<Customer> custList = getListObjectWithConditionInXMLFile(Customer.class);
```

Comment: Nice that you even forgot to change the generic type from `E` to `T` after you copied my code example..

Comment: Now Amended. Before the answer just gave basic idea for generics implementation and since you implemented, I thought of providing the implementation too. If you're not happy, I can remove the definition.